# Repeated Protocol in Address of WCF Service

Tags: wcf

I have seen two styles of addresses for WCF endpoints in consuming applications:

1. http://someserver.com/someservice.svc
2. http://someserver.com/someservice.svc/http

It seems that the protocol is repeated after the service address and a slash. Sometimes only one or the other will work, and sometimes both will work. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most things, this was a case of me not understanding the question I was asking.

It turns out that you can specify an "address" in the endpoint section of a web.config that allows you to change bindings (which includes the protocol), binding configuration, and contracts. This means you can do this in your web.config:

```
<services>
  <service name="someName">
    <endpoint address="http" binding="httpBinding" contract="com.IService"/>
    <endpoint address="tcp" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="com.IService"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Doing that allows me to specify different protocols for the same service (assuming I have configured the corresponding bindings in the web.config to use those protocols).

Further confusion arose from whether I was using WCF Test Client, adding service references in Visual Studio, or specifying the address. When adding references in Visual Studio or WCF Test Client, using the "address" portion caused it not to work because WCF uses that for exposing metadata with the metadata exchange address (http://someserver.com/someservice.svc/mex). However, when specifying the address for a service, I must include the "address" portion in order to specify the endpoint I wish to use.